# tvML / TVOS : Template with Json & Prototype

Tags: javascript, json, tvos, tvml, tvjs

So i want to have a json file that holds my images with titles. I tried to do it with prototypes in tvML. This is the guide i followed. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TVMLKitJS/Conceptual/TVMLProgrammingGuide/GeneratingContentForYourApp.html

Basically, i have the exact code from 5-6 and the images.json file with type, ID and url.

Somehow when i start the app, i only get the Banner which says : JSON Shelf. But i dont get the images, or even a shelf where i see blank lockups. (Isnt working when i use my own images aswell).

Any idea how to do this? Is the code from the documentation on devoler.apple.com just outdated?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but then I realized I was using Xcode 8.3.3 which is on tvOS 10.x. Prototypes is only supported in tvOS 11+. Make sure you upgrade to Xcode 9